# My randrange code in python is not working

Tags: python-2.7

I have some code and it's not working

what I'm trying to do is make it check for the chances and add elifs if any other chance is happening, but it is only doing an if and one elif. Also, I replaced all the elifs with ifs and a lot of them were happening

here is the code

```
import time
import random

bean1 = ["Berry Blue", "Toothpaste"]
bean2 = ["Cappuccino", "Liver & Onions"]
bean3 = ["Tutti-Fruitti", "Stinky Socks"]
bean4 = ["Toasted Marshmallow", "Stink Bug"]
bean5 = ["Pomegranate", "Old Bandage"]
bean6 = ["Peach", "Barf"]
bean7 = ["Birthday Cake", "Dirty Dishwater"]
bean8 = ["Strawberry Banana Smoothie", "Dead Fish"]
bean9 = ["Juicy Pear", "Booger"]
bean10 = ["Buttered Popcorn", "Rotten Egg"]

print(" ")
print("Hello, and welcome to bean boozled")
time.sleep(1)

while True:
    bean1_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean2_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean3_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean4_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean5_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean6_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean7_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean8_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean9_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)
    bean10_chance = random.randrange(1, 100)

    print(" ")
    spin = raw_input("Spin or press q to quit (spin/q): ").lower()
    print(" ")
    time.sleep(1)
    if spin == "spin":
        if bean1_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean1))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean1)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean2_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean2))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat2 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat2 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean2)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean3_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean3))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat3 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat3 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean3)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean4_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean4))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat4 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat4 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean4)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean5_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean5))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat5 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat5 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean5)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean6_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean6))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat6 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat6 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean6)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean7_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean7))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
        veat7 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat7 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean7)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean8_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean8))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat8 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat8 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean8)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean9_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean9))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat9 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat9 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean9)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
        elif bean10_chance <= 50:
            print("You got " + str(bean10))
            print(" ")
            time.sleep(1)
            eat10 = raw_input("Eat the bean (eat): ").lower()
            if eat10 == "eat":
                print(" ")
                print("It tastes like " + str(random.choice(bean10)))
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print("Not an option")
    elif spin == "q":
        print("Goodbye")
        print(" ")
        time.sleep(1)
        break
    else:
        print("Not an option")
        print(" ")
        time.sleep(1)
```

It won't look for the other elifs it will just do bean1_chance and bean2_chance

Comment: If your beans will increase in the future, say from 10 to 1000, will you write other 990 elif copy-paste statements? Disregarding the problem in question this looks like a very poor design choice and it undermines the understandability of your code

Comment: It you want to check all beans you don not want elif (which  only happens if the previous test was false). Also, you probably want to look into loops and lists/arrays.